# Swift - Selecting cells when having multiple custom cell-classes

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have 2 custom cells that I need to set the selection properties for. Right now, I've used a boolean to tell the program that the cell is either type 1 or type 2, because I was just checking if the code was working.

Now I need the program to find out which type of cell it is by itself, and I don't know how it's done.

My code looks like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if istrue{
        let mySelectedCell: CustomTableCell = tv.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as CustomTableCell

        if (mySelectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark) {
            mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

            if let tx = mySelectedCell.customLabel.text as String!{

                var textLabel:String = String()
                textLabel = tx

                println(textLabel)

                if let ind = find(tempList, textLabel) {
                    tempList.removeAtIndex(ind)
                    println(tempList)

                }
            }
        }

        else {

            mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            mySelectedCell.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

            if let tx = mySelectedCell.customLabel.text as String!{

                var textLabel:String = String()
                textLabel = tx
                tempList.append(textLabel)

                println(tempList)
            }
        }

        }else{
            let mySelectedCell: CustomTableCell2 = tv.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as CustomTableCell2

            if (mySelectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark) {
                mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

                if let tx = mySelectedCell.titleLabel.text as String!{

                    var textLabel:String = String()
                    textLabel = tx

                    println(textLabel)

                    if let ind = find(tempList, textLabel) {
                        tempList.removeAtIndex(ind)
                        println(tempList)

                    }
                }
            }

            else {

                mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
                mySelectedCell.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

                if let tx = mySelectedCell.titleLabel.text as String!{

                    var textLabel:String = String()
                    textLabel = tx
                    tempList.append(textLabel)

                    println(tempList)
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

I don't know if this is the best way of doing it either, so please give me some tips if you have a better way to set this "checkmark" selection-style.

All suggestions on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Objective example of this:

```
id cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([cell isKindOfClass:[PhotoCell2x class]]) {
    NSLog(@"1");
}
else if([cell isKindOfClass:[EffectCell2x class]]){
    NSLog(@"2");
}
```

If I get time i'll add a swift version. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thank you, I used ismemberofclass instead of iskindofclass :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is updated for **Swift 4** for anyone that needs it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if (cell?.isMember(of: CLASSNAME.self))!{
        print("hello")
    } else {

    }
}
```